# Как зарегистрировать массив классов через luabridge?

Tags: c++, lua

Допустим, у меня есть такой с++ класс:

```
struct Enemy{
    int x;
    int y;
    int health;

    //...
};
```

И есть вектор элементов класса:

```
std::vector<Enemy> enemies;
```

Необходимо зарегистрировать этот массив через luabridge так, чтобы можно было так обращаться к элементам класса через Lua:

```
enemies[5]:x = enemies[5]:x+1
```

Как это можно реализовать? Я знаю как зарегистрировать класс, функцию или переменную, но функции для создания элемента класса я не находил.

Заранее спасибо!